# Join on two columns but know which one (or both) were matched on

Tags: sql

I have two tables, each with two columns. The first table is a pair of IDs, the second table maps IDs (that can appear in either or both of the columns in the first table) to another ID.

```
col_a        | col_b
--------------------
42           | 555
555          | 73
61           | 22
444          | 444
```

```
col_x        | col_y
--------------------
555          | 2999
444          | 3333
```

I would like to look up IDs in `col_a`/`col_b` in the first table and if they're in `col_x`, replace their value with the value in `col_y`, so the desired result is

```
col_a        | col_b
--------------------
42           | 2999
2999         | 73
61           | 22
3333         | 3333
```

I can do this with two joins

```sql
select
  coalesce(join_a.col_y, col_a) as col_a,
  coalesce(join_b.col_y, col_b) as col_a
from
  table_1
    left join table_2 join_a on table_1.col_a = join_a.col_x
    left join table_2 join_b on table_1.col_b = join_b.col_x
```

but is there a more efficient way? In real life I actually have multiple tables like the second table but I'm also able to tell if an ID will appear in one of those tables by looking at the ID (because it's a string).

Comment: What do your IDs really look like?

Comment: I don't think that there is a more efficient way.  You need to independently match col_a against the other table and col_b against that table.  That requires 2 left joins.  If performance is your main issue, then I would perhaps look at how you have the col_x, col_y table set up physically in the database e.g. with a primary key vs. sorted primary key vs. indexes, etc.  The joins should be pretty efficient since there are no >,<, or operations, etc to make a full table scan happen.

Comment: @shawnt00 essentially a string with a prefix of the name of the table they're in followed by a unique ID

Comment: If the two values within a single row each could be matched to distinct rows in the lookup then you'll absolutely need to do two joins/subqueries.